# Google places autocomplete api limits

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, ios6, google-places-api

I have a doubt about limit on google places api. [Google doc](https://developers.google.com/places/policies#usage_limits)'s *Usage Limits* section says that limit is 1000 requests per 24 hour period. That I understand.

But last line in that section says that **Text Search is subject to a 10 times multiplier, causing each Text Search request to count as 10 requests against your quota.**

So is *places autocomplete* and *place details api* is considered a text search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are referring specifically to [Text Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests) (a separate service from Autocomplete and Details).  [Radar Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#RadarSearchRequests) have a similar multiplier (5x).